# having trouble parsing an array in php

Tags: php, php-parser

Just starting with php and sorry if this is a newbie question but i'm having problems parsing a array.

I get this value(output of print_r($result);):

```
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( 
       [Master_companyname] => Royal Bank of Canada 
       [ticker] => ry-t 
       [base_table] => Master 
       [base_field] => ticker 
       [set] => 
           [rendered] =>
              Companyname:
              Ticker:
              Companyname:
       [finder_element_1_Master_companyname] => Royal Bank of Canada 
       [field_names] => Array ( 
            [1] => finder_element_1_Master_companyname 
            ) 
       ) 
   )
```

I want to extract only **ry-t** but not sure how.  Here's what I tried

```
$result1 = implode('=>', $result);
print_r($result);
```

and

```
print (float)substr($result1, strpos($result1, "=")+1);
```

I studied a bit of java and python and I was trying to apply the same logic of converting it to a string and then splitting the text by a delimiting(in this case I thought "=>").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to subscript the array member, and then the `ticker` property.

```
echo $result[0]->ticker;
```

Comment: omg thank you so much.  I can't believe its so simple.  I have probably written like 50 lines of code trying to parse this file.  Thank you so much Alex.